# orientdb - database backup zero byte file

Tags: orientdb

orientDB backup is creating zero byte file. 
error is as below :-

> Error: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: backup
>
> orientdb {db=isc}> connect remote:localhost/isc root admin
>
> Disconnecting from the database [isc]...OK Connecting to database
>   [remote:localhost/isc] with user 'root'...OK
>
> CONFIGURED SERVERS orientdb {db=isc}> BACKUP DATABASE
>   C:\IntelliSURF\backup\june22_ORDB.zip Executing full backup of
>   database 'isc' to: DATABASE C:\IntelliSURF\backup\june22_ORDB.zip...
>
> Backup executed in 0.00 seconds Error:
>   java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: backup
>
> orientdb {db=isc}>

Version is - orientdb-community-2.2.0-beta  on Windows Server 2008 R2 standard

Answer (score 1):

OrientDB Community Edition does not support backing up remote databases. OrientDB Enterprise Edition does support this feature.

Hope it helps.

Regards

Comment: I am using local host and local database.  If remote host is used error will be "Error: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: backup is not supported against remote storage. Open the database with plocal or use Enterprise Edition"

Comment: ok, but the community edition doesn't support backup command with remote access, only enterprise edition does
http://orientdb.com/docs/last/Console-Command-Backup.html
You are using the remote connection